How to remove unused keys by using i18n-unused

yarn i18n-unused display-unused

Unused translations in:\Users\Amar\Downloads\githubissue\common.json
Unused translations count: 1
(index)  Translation
0        '6'         

Total unused translations count: 1
Can free up memory: ~0.003kb**
Amar@Amar MINGW64 ~/Downloads/githubissues $ yarn i18n-unused remove-unused
Successfully removed: C:\Users\Amar\Downloads\githubissues\common.json
Amar@Amar MINGW64 ~/Downloads/githubissues $ yarn i18n-unused display-unused
Unused translations in:Users\Amar\Downloads\githubissues\common.json
Unused translations count: 1
(index)  Translation
0        '6'
Total unused translations count: 1
Can free up memory: ~0.003kb**
I want to remove unused keys from json file
i am using yarn i18n-unused remove-unused
